# frame type in python

Tags: python, execution

In a `python reference manual` said that

> A code block is executed in an execution frame. A frame contains some
>   administrative information (used for debugging) and determines where
>   and how execution continues after the code block’s execution has
>   completed.

and

> Frame objects represent execution frames. They may occur
>   in traceback objects

But I don't understanf how frame does work. How can I get an acces to a current frame object? When is frame object creating? Is the frame object created everytime when a code of new block is strarting to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These frames are representations of the stack frames created by function calls. You should not need to access them in normal programming. A new frame is indeed created every time a function is called, and destroyed when it exits or raises an uncaught exception. Since function calls can go many levels deep your program ends up with a bunch of nested stack frames, but it's not good programming practice (unless you are writing a debugger or similar application) to mess about with the frames even though Python does make them available.

Comment: So it is not clear why did in the spec defines the frame type?

Comment: Because if you want to process exception tracebacks automatically, or if you want to play games by tweaking the calling namespace from inside a function, you need to have access to the real guts of the system. So it is possible to write introspective code that (for example) allows you to run Python statements inside the namespace of the currently-executing function while your program is suspended, or display the entire content of the call stack for examination. It's fairly open.

Comment: Python 3's new `breakpoint()` call makes it easier to need frames, and pass them on to contexts. Similarly `sys.excepthook()` allows (e.g.) saving frames from an exception on a production server and later re-formatting them for Slack, ...

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand frames in Python 3, especially if you maintain production code that is sensitive to memory usage, such as deep learning models.

Frames are objects that represent areas of memory where local variables are stored when a function is called. They can be stored and manipulated, which is what debuggers do. Understanding how frames are handled by python can help you avoid memory leaks.

Each time a function is called, a new frame is created to hold the function's variables and parameters. These frames are normally destroyed when the function finishes executing normally. However, if an exception is raised, the associated frame and all parent frames are stored in a traceback object, which is an attribute of the Exception object (`__traceback__`). This can cause memory leaks if the Exception object live for a long time, because they will hold onto the frames and all associated local variables are not going to be garbage collected.

This matter quite a lot.

For example it is one reason why you need to call the `close` method on `file` objects even if you don't create reference cycles, because the file object may be referenced by a traceback object stored on an Exception. This exclude file from being garbage collected even after it goes out of scope.

The issue is worse in interactive python shells like (Jupyter) where each unhandled exceptions ends up leaving forever in few places. I'm working on a way to clear that up hence I've found this issue.

In Python, the types module provides the `FrameType` and `TracebackType` types, which represent frames and tracebacks, respectively. However, you cannot instantiate these types directly. https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FrameType

The **tracback** attribute was introduced in python 3 with [PEP 3134](https://peps.python.org/pep-3134/), it goes a bit on ramification of this change in details, so it is a good read for curious.